# Change size of a childnode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parent-child, child-nodes

I have 2 SKSpritenodes: robot & computer
robot is the parentNode and computer is the childNode

```
 robot.addChild(computer)
```

Now I want to change the size of the computer by just using the name of the parentNode.
So I need a code like: robot.childnode.size.width = xxx
How can I do this?

the reason for this: I have multiple skspritenodes called robot and I can detect them with collision which one it is, so I need this code to acces the childnode of that particular parentNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a name for the `computer` node when you are adding it to `robot`.

```
computer.name = "computer"
robot.addChild(computer)
```

Later on you can write...

```
if let computer = robot.childNodeWithName("computer") as? SKSpriteNode {
    // you can install El Capitain and change the properties of computer here
}
```

... or if you prefer the single line version:

```
(robot.childNodeWithName("computer") as? SKSpriteNode)?.size.height = 100
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: And how do I acces the parent from the childnode? childNode.parent.size doesn't work..

Comment: I cannot test it right now but try this '(childNode.parent as? SKSpriteNode)?.size.height = 100'